# missing terminals in gnuplot on mac osx yosemite

Tags: gnuplot, x11, osx-yosemite

Im trying to install gnuplot on my mac but im missing several terminals, such as the png, x11, aqua etc. Ive tried googling and found some people having similar issues, but none of their tricks seems to work.

Ive tried reinstalling gnuplot several times, with the " --with-x11 --with-aquaterm" commands etc. but it does still not work. I have also reinstalled Xquartz, but that did not help. Any suggestions? Im not really familiar with these things so please explain it in simple terms :)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use brew to install gnuplot (the latest version in brew is 5.0.5 which is pretty recent):

from [brew homepage](http://brew.sh/)

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

then you simply have to type

```
brew install gnuplot --with-x11
```